# MIPS assembly: memory gets overwritten in stack by another subroutine

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

For the last 3 days I'm working on an assignment which asks us to implement the Quicksort algorithm in MIPS. We are given this piece of C code:

```
void swap(int v[], int k, int l) {
  int temp = v[k];
  v[k] = v[l];
  v[l] = temp;
}

int partition(int v[], int n) {
  int pivot = v[n-1];
  int i = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) 
    if (v[j] < pivot) 
      swap(v,i++,j);

  swap(v, i, n - 1);
  return (i);
}

void qsort(int v[], int n) {

  if (n > 1) {
    int p = partition(v, n);
    qsort(v,p);
    qsort(&v[p+1],n-p-1);
  }
}
```

and we are asked to 'translate' it in MIPS. The `partition()` function is given to us in MIPS, and we have to implement the other two (`qsort()` and `swap()`). Well, `swap()` is tested and working, so I'm trying to implement `qsort()` and I need to store in the stack the addresses where `qsort()` will return to after it's done (for the recursion). The problem is, that no matter what I do, be it playing around with the stack and frame pointers or explicitly trying to set empty cells, when `partition()` is executed, it **replaces** my array with some of its *own* data. Any ideas on solving that?

My code is here (anything without comments is not mine, ignore the jumps to printArray, I'm leaving it out due to it having no relation with the rest of the code):

```
    .globl  v
    .data
    .align  2
v:
    .word   3
    .word   10
    .word   8
    .word   2
    .word   7
    .word   1
    .word   5
    .word   9
    .word   6
    .word   4
    .text

main:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
    sw      $ra,36($sp)
    sw      $fp,32($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    li      $v0,10          # 0xa
    move    $s0, $v0
    sw      $v0,28($fp)
    lw      $a1,28($fp)
    la      $a0, v

    jal     printArray

    lw      $a1,28($fp)
    la      $a0, v

    jal     qsort

    la      $a0, v
    move    $a1, $s0
    jal     printArray

    move    $v0,$0
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw      $ra,36($sp)
    lw      $fp,32($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,40
    jr      $ra


swap:
    move    $t0, $a0    #store the address of the first cell of the array (we need this for finding v[k]'s address)
    move    $t1, $a0    #same as above (need this for the address of v[l])
    move    $t4, $a1    #load k into t4
    sll     $t4, $t4, 2 #turn k into bytes to be offset
    add     $t0, $a0, $t4   #find the address of v[k]
    move    $t4, $a2    #load l into a1
    sll     $t4, $t4, 2 #turn l into bytes to be offset
    add     $t1, $a0, $t4   #find the address of v[l]
    lw      $t2, 0($t0)     #store the element with index k in t2 (t2: temp in the C code)
    lw      $t3, 0($t1) #store the element with index l in t3
    sw      $t2, 0($t1) #store the element with index k in the address where v[l] was
    sw      $t3, 0($t0) #store v[l] where v[k] was

    jr      $ra
    nop


partition:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-56
    sw  $ra,44($sp)
    sw  $fp,40($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $a0,48($fp)
    sw  $a1,52($fp)
    lw  $v1,52($fp)
    li  $v0,1073676288          # 0x3fff0000
    ori $v0,$v0,0xffff
    addu    $v0,$v1,$v0
    sll $v0,$v0,2
    lw  $v1,48($fp)
    addu    $v0,$v1,$v0
    lw  $v0,0($v0)
    sw  $v0,36($fp)
    sw  $0,28($fp)
    sw  $0,32($fp)
    b   part_loop
    nop

part_for:
    lw  $v0,32($fp)
    sll $v0,$v0,2
    lw  $v1,48($fp)
    addu    $v0,$v1,$v0
    lw  $v1,0($v0)
    lw  $v0,36($fp)
    slt $v0,$v1,$v0
    beq $v0,$0,part_noswap
    nop

    lw  $v0,28($fp)
    addiu   $v1,$v0,1
    sw  $v1,28($fp)
    lw  $a2,32($fp)
    move    $a1,$v0
    lw  $a0,48($fp)

    jal swap

part_noswap:
    lw  $v0,32($fp)
    addiu   $v0,$v0,1
    sw  $v0,32($fp)
part_loop:
    lw  $v0,52($fp)
    addiu   $v1,$v0,-1
    lw  $v0,32($fp)
    slt $v0,$v0,$v1
    bne $v0,$0,part_for
    nop

    lw  $v0,52($fp)
    addiu   $v0,$v0,-1
    move    $a2,$v0
    lw  $a1,28($fp)
    lw  $a0,48($fp)
    jal swap

    lw  $v0,28($fp)
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $ra,44($sp)
    lw  $fp,40($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,56
    jr  $ra


qsort:
    move    $t5, $ra    #store temporarily the ret.addr. of qsort's caller
    jal     RetAddrMng  #then store it on the stack
    addi    $t6, $t6, 1 #add 1 to t6, which counts the number of times qsort has been called
    bgt     $a1, 1, sort    #sorting will continue if n > 1

sort:
    jal     partition
    move    $a1, $v0        #move 'p' from result to be the argument of the next qsort
    jal     qsort
    jr      $ra

RetAddrMng:
    sll     $t6, $t6, 2 #turn the number of times into offset bytes by quadrupling them
    add     $sp, $sp, $t6   #move the stack pointer 4*<number of times> bytes to find the next cell
    sw      $t5, 0($sp) #store the address in t5 into the stack
    srl     $t6, $t6, 2 #we will need again the number of times, so we invert the transformation by dividing with 4
    jr      $ra     #continue with qsort
```

FYI, I'm running on MARS 4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you need `$t6` for and why you are **adding** it to `sp` and why you are adding more and more.

Comment: `$t6` is there to keep track how many times `qsort` is "called". I've observed that `partition` always returns the stack pointer to its original position, so by adding 4*`$t6` to the stack pointer I move it to the cell after the one the previous address was written on. Also, I'm adding it to `sp` because if I subtract, it will overwrite my data from the first call, while adding saves it (at least for one call)

Comment: That didn't clear things up for me and whatever you want to do with that is probably wrong. Yes, `partition` should return `$sp` unchanged as all functions should. I don't understand why you need to somehow dynamically address stuff higher up on the stack. That's almost certainly wrong or at least overcomplicated.

Comment: Could you propose a better way of storing those addresses in the stack? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to store something on the stack you just decrement the stack pointer by the size of your item and write it there. That is a local variable. Since you will restore `$sp` to the previous value at function exit, it will be freed automatically. But you already seem to be using that, so why not for `$ra` too?

Comment: I actually tried decrementing the stack pointer. The problem is, that `qsort` is recursive, so this space must not be freed, because we need the addresses until `qsort` has ran for the last time. Then we start freeing the space.

Comment: I don't understand. You do not need all the addresses. Recursion works by storing stuff on the stack as described. Maybe try a recursive factorial first to see how it's done.

Comment: OK, I'll try it later because I need to go. Thanks.